Assembly import problem in a PowerShell script
I'm doing a project that involves retrieving Outlook calendars from webmail.
To do this, I'm using Exchange, which asks me to download a C# project that I need to compile into an assembly (.dll file). I then put this assembly into the PowerShell script. Everything works until I put the .dll file in the PowerShell script. I import it like this:
Add-Type -Path "***********\Reference.dll" 

The path is hidden for greater security, but in the script the path is correct.
the PowerShell script returns the error :
Add-Type: Unable to load one or more of the required types. Extract the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

And if I use what the script suggests, I get :
Unable to load the file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The specified file is 
not found.
Unable to load the file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The specified 
file cannot be found.

However, I have checked and System.ServiceModel.Primitives is present and version 8.0.0 of System.Runtime does not exist. The latest version of System.Runtime is 4.3.1.
Do you have any solutions? Or has someone already encountered this problem?

Sorry, I thought I had. I'll add this

It sounds like you may have compiled the assembly for a newer version of .NET than what your chosen version of PowerShell supports.

I've just seen that the organisation where I'm doing my work placement uses an old version of PowerShell.

For Windows PowerShell you'll need to target .NET Framework 4.5 for ABI compatibility, none of the modern .NET versions will work

I've updated PowerShell and the problem remains the same. The errors don't change.

Updated PowerShell to what version? How did you compile the C# project and what version of .NET did you target? We can't see your screen :)

I used version net8.0 with PowerShell version 7.4.2.

And you still get a loader exception saying it cannot resolve System.Runtime version 8.0.0?

Yes indeed, but I don't understand why, given that the latest version of System.Runtime is 4.3.1.
